# Magento Database Compaibility Between Versions

Tags: database

I'm looking to upgrade a site from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.0.1.  From what I understand, once the 1.9 upgrade is run for the first time, it will update the database as necessary.

Temporarily, I would like to be able to switch back and forward between the 1.7 and 1.9 versions, using the same DB.

Will this be possible or will it cause problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each version of Magento generally introduces schema changes and sometimes has to manipulate data to fit into the new schemas during the database upgrade process. Once the database is upgraded, it will only be valid for the new version of Magento you are now running. In some (minor upgrade) cases it may still be functional on the old codebase, but I would *never expect* that to be possible. An example of a case where it would *most likely work* would be upgrading from 1.9.0.0 to 1.9.0.1 because it's a minor patch release which also happens to not introduce any schema changes. In your case, however, since you're upgrading two major versions forward, I would expect and venture to say that it's more likely the 1.7 code will simply not function against a 1.9 database.

**My recommendation...**

Don't do it. Even if 1.7 seems to work running against the 1.9 database, you're putting yourself at risk of data loss because you're running code against schemas which it was never tested with. If you need to run 1.7 as a reference, keep a copy of the database around to use for running the reference site and keep the 1.9 database with the 1.9 code.

Comment: Good explaination... Davidalgar

Comment: So the conclusion is: "Once you go 1.9 you never go back."